# How do I unlock the red gun?

Tags: antichamber

In Antichamber, I have managed to access a room adjacent to the room with the red gun. There seems to be a locked door with a mechanism with green lasers and a shape made with yellow blocks.

[image: The room with the red gun]

I cannot manage to block the laser or remove the yellow blocks with my blue gun, which is the the only weapon I have so far. Am I stuck because this puzzle is unsolvable without unlocking another colored gun first or should I try harder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to get the green gun first, then the yellow, then red.

Comment: It would be better if you showed or linked how to get the previous guns too.